# Very simple question on Console vs Script in R

Tags: r

I have just started to learn to code on R, so I apologize for the very simple question. I understand it is best to type your code in as a Script so you can edit and save it. However, when I try to make an object in the script section, it does not work. If I make an object in the console, R saves the object and it appears in my environment. I am typing in a very simple code to try a quick exercise on rolling dice:

```
die <- 1:6
```

But it only works in the console and not when typed as a script. Any help/explanation appreciated!

Comment: Are you using and IDE like Rstudio ? Or only R. A script must be executed/run.

Comment: "it is best to type your code in as a Script so you can edit and save" -- better to say that "it is best to type your code in as a Script so you can edit, save, and *source* it as needed". Use the `source` option in RStudio (assuming that this is what you are using)

Comment: The answer depends on your operating system. On a Mac you just put the cursor on the line you want to execute in the script file and press Apple Key-Enter. In Windows and Linux I think you would need to copy/paste the line from the script file into the Consol. It is an extra step but it also lets you run multiple lines at a time.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your answers. I understand now that the code on the script needs to be "run" rather than just pressing enter. I am doing this now and my objects have been saved. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you interact with R environment differently when running an .R script via RScript.exe or via console with R.exe, Rterm, etc. and in GUI IDEs like RGui or RStudio. (This applies to any programming language with interactive compilers not just R).

The script *does* save the`die` object in R environment but only during the run or lifetime of that script (i.e., from beginning to end of code lines). Your code line is simply an assignment of object. You do nothing with it. Apply some function, output results, and other actions in that script to see.

On the console, the R environment persists interactively until you quit it with `q()`. So assigned objects remains for lifetime of your console session. After assigning, you can afterwards apply function, output results, or other actions in line by line calls.

Ultimately, scripts gathers all line by line code in advance of run for automated execution without relying on user to supply lines. Imagine running 1,000 lines of code with nested `if`/`then` or `for`/`while` loops, `apply` functions on console! Therefore, have all your R coding needs summarily handled in scripts.

Comment: This was a really helpful explanation! I have now got my code to work :)

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help a new useR!

Comment: I didn't know this, thank you! I have ticked the check mark now!

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to have the script, as you say, you can save edit correct, without having to rewrite the code to change a variable or number.

I recommend using Rstudio, it is very practical and will help you to program more efficiently and allows you to see, among other things, the different objects that you have created.

Comment: I am using Rstudio now. Thank you!